# Stretching a Hexagon

Tags: geometry, area, polygons

Consider the regular hexagon

[image]

Imagine I want to stretch it uniformly in the horizontal direction ($x$). In order to keep the area constant, I naturally need to compress it in the vertical direction ($y$). In the end, all I'm doing is changing the aspect ratio of the hexagon. The perimeter, however, will change.

[image]

For a given stretching factor in the $x$ direction, $h_x$, how do I find the stretching factor $h_y$ such that the area $A$ is constant?

Also, how do I find the perimeter as a function of $h_x$, $P(h_x)$?

I understand my question is relatively broad, and no attempt at solving it is presented. I'm looking for hints and ideas.

Comment: If you have done linear algebra, area change of a two dimensional linear transformation is as being multiplied by the (absolute value of) the determinant of the transformation matrix. In three dimensions it is the same but for volume.

Comment: As for your first question: if you stretch by a factor of $a$ on the x-axis, and by a factor of $b$ on the y-axis, the area change will simply be $ab$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the area, the easy way to visualize this is to divide the figure into tiny squares. then the area is the sum of the area of the squares $$A=\sum_i A_i$$
When you stretch the figure, you will stretch each individual square into a rectangle. If the side of the individual square was $a$, the sides of the rectangle are now $h_x a$ and $h_y a$, so the new area of the figure will be $$A'=h_x h_y A$$ If you want $A=A'$, then $h_y=1/h_x$.

For the perimeter it gets more complicated, because individual sides change lengths in different ways. But you can still come up with a simple algorithm. Each side has originally some length $l_i$ that we can write as a combination of length along the $x$ axis and along $y$ axis using Pythagoras' theorem:$$l_i=\sqrt{l_{ix}^2+l_{iy}^2}$$You know now how each component stretches, so $$l_i'=\sqrt{h_x^2l_{ix}^2+\frac{1}{h_x^2}l_{iy}^2}$$