# Computing an ellipse's area by substitution

Tags: algebra-precalculus, conic-sections, area

I want to do it by substitution, please don't put an answer that isn't about substitution.

Say I go from something like this $\frac{x²}{c²}+\frac{y²}{d²}=k²$ to $\frac{x²}{a²}+\frac{y²}{b²}=1$.

Let $x=a\frac{u}{b}$, the equation becomes then that of a circle: $\frac{u²}{b²}+\frac{y²}{b²}=1$. The area is then $\pi\left(\frac{u²}{b²}+\frac{y²}{b²}\right)=\pi\left(\frac{x²}{a²}+\frac{y²}{b²}\right)$ which is wrong, where is the problem?

Comment: $x$ and $y$ are interconnected in the equation. So, .....

Answer (score 3):

The problem with what you tried is that the $(x,y)$ and $(u,y)$ dimensions are not the same. In $(u,y)$ dimensions you have

$$u^2 + y^2 = b^2 \tag{1}\label{eq1A}$$

This is a standard equation for a circle centered at the origin, with radius $|b|$ and area $b^2\pi$.

For using $(x,y)$ dimensions, you have the transformation equation of

$$x = \left(\frac{a}{b}\right)u \tag{2}\label{eq2A}$$

This applies a horizontal stretch or compression factor of $\left|\frac{a}{b}\right|$. Thus, the resulting new area in $(x,y)$ co-ordinates would be the original area in $(u,y)$ co-ordinates multiplied by this factor (e.g., as explained in the [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3453304/602049) to [Stretching a Hexagon](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3453261/stretching-a-hexagon)). As such, the area of the ellipse

$$\frac{x^2}{a^2} + \frac{y^2}{b^2} = 1 \tag{3}\label{eq3A}$$

would be

$$\left(b^2\pi\right)\left|\frac{a}{b}\right| = |ab|\pi \tag{4}\label{eq4A}$$

This is the standard formula for the area of an ellipse.

Note you can also do this in the other direction. Suppose you let $A_e(a,b)$ be the area of an ellipse with an equation given in \eqref{eq3A}. Then you can apply the transformation equation

$$u = \left(\frac{b}{a}\right)x \tag{5}\label{eq5A}$$

to get \eqref{eq1A}, which is an equation of a circle with area $\pi b^2$. As the transformation applies a horizontal stretch or compression factor of $\left|\frac{b}{a}\right|$, the resulting area of the circle would be the area of the ellipse multiplied by this, i.e., you get

$$\pi b^2 = \left|\frac{b}{a}\right|A_e(a,b) \tag{6}\label{eq6A}$$

Comment: Hello Mr. John, and thank you for your answer! What I was looking for, though, was not an analogy but an algebraic derivation. Can we not get $\pi b^2=\frac{b}{a}A_{ellipse}$ algebraically?

Comment: @Luyw You're welcome for my answer. Thank you for explaining further. However, I'm not quite sure what you're looking for, but I have an idea. I extended my answer to show how you can do the substitution/transformation, and thus the horizontal stretching or compressing, in the opposite direction as well, thus basically getting the formula you're asking for. If this isn't what you want, please explain further. Note there are also other derivation methods, such as using substitution when using integrals to calculate the area, but I don't think that's what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Consider how the circle becomes an elongated ellipse. Although not strictly pre-calculus, area finding for variable ordinates is by integration... *each* vertical strip area increases from $y_1 dx$  to $ y_2 dx$ where $y_2>y_1,$ that is multiplied by a constant factor.

Area is computed by integration, and $y_2>y_1$ being a constant can be taken out of the integral sign.

There is a *constant* stretch factor along y- direction

$$ = \frac{y_2}{y_1} =\frac{b}{a}, \,b>a. $$

Area $ \pi a^2 = \pi a\cdot a$ becomes $ \pi \,\dfrac{b}{a} a\cdot a =\pi b a$

Comment: Thank you for your answer :) But I knew about the constant $y_2/y_1$ and thus taking out the constant in integration.